# TSLint Error "Expected a 'for-of' loop instead of a 'for' loop with this simple iteration"

Tags: javascript, typescript, lint, tslint

I have a for loop to get an ID from the DB:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.GetContractId.length; i++) {
    if (data.GetContractId[i].ContractId) {
        this.contractExists = true;
    }
}
```

Now I get the following TSLint-Error:

> Expected a 'for-of' loop instead of a 'for' loop with this simple iteration

I'm not sure how to use it in this instance, can anyone help?

Comment: can you give an example of the structure that `data.GetContractId` has?  is this a function? is an array? a single value? an object?

Comment: @CalvinNunes GetContractID is an array and it returns and Object that has the field ContractID in it

Comment: something like this then: `data.GetContractId = [{ContractId: 1}]`  ?

Comment: Don't forget to `break` the loop after finding a match.

Comment: I have update my answer and offer to use some method @bobdolan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TSLint** see that you could use for-of instead of for-loop it's just enhanced and more cleaner

```
for (let contract of data.GetContractId) {
  if (contract.ContractId) {
    this.contractExists = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

But you can use `some` method on array objects

```
 this.contractExists  = data.GetContractId.some(contract => contract.ContractId);
```

> The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array
>   passes the test implemented by the provided function.

[some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)