# Dynamic Search Filter in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

I want to write a generic filter in angular 7 to perform search filter operation on any field in any number of screens. I have found some links suggesting writing custom pipe filters but they always filter based on particular static field.

To explain more, I have around 20 screens in my project. Each screen is making an API call , fetching data and displaying on the UI ,like one is device screen showing data for fields:

```
deviceId, deviceHardwareNumber, deviceSoftwareNumber, deviceVendor, devicePurchaseDate
```

Another screen for deviceServiceDetails

```
deviceId, deviceServiceProvider, deviceServiceDate, nextServiceDueDate
```

Now either I can write 20 filters for 20 screens for filtering on different field names or is there any way possible for writing only one filter for all the screens and filtering on any field.

Is there a way to make it dynamic by writing one filter irrespective of the number of screens, i.e. any list or searchText passed from any screen should be filtered and returned?

Comment: Can you provide more details? What is the list of data you would like to filter from?

Comment: Edited the question to add in more details

Comment: Oh, alright, so it is something like filtering through an array of objects, but with dynamic filtering?

Comment: Yes , I want to filter through the array of objects being displayed on UI using ngFor but with dyanamic filtering

Comment: I explained how to do it here. It works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55060545/angular-search-bar-in-typescript-table/55061017#55061017

Comment: So you want to do exactly what the official Angular documentation recommends not to  do? https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Answer (score 2):

It 's hard to create a filter to handle every case scenario but I did something to handle string value and with option to enter the property name in that case I manage to use this filter in many screens , but you can see if you want to handle another type you may need to create a new filter in that case

In case of filter a string property with support different method like include , equal and not equal

*string filter pipe*

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(arr: any[], prop: string, value: string , method:Method): any {
    if (arr) {
      if (!value) {
        return arr
      } else {
        return arr.filter(obj => this.filter(obj[prop],value, method))
      }
    } else {
      return []
    }
  }

  filter(source :string, target :string, method:Method) : boolean {

    switch(method) {
      case "includes" : return source.includes(target)
      case "equal"  : return source === target
      case "not-equal" : return source !== target
    }
  }
}

type Method ="includes" | "equal" | "not-equal"
```

*template*

```
<p>
Include <br>
 <input type="text" placeholder="search..." [(ngModel)]="searchValue">
</p>

<div *ngFor="let skill of skills | filter :'name' : searchValue: 'includes' ">
  {{skill.name}}
</div> 


<p>
Equal <br>
 <input type="text" placeholder="search..." [(ngModel)]="searchValue02">
</p>

<div *ngFor="let skill of skills | filter :'name' : searchValue02 : 'equal'">
  {{skill.name}}
</div>
```

[**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-string-filter-pipe)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the issue is already solved as I have updated in the comments above.

Comment: @Tarun both answers can work for you but in my answer you can select the property and the method you want ,happy to help 

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Regex instead of includes() to get case in-sensitive filter results.

```
case "includes" : return source.includes(target); Case Sensitive

case "includes" : return new RegExp(target, "i").test(source); Case Insensitive
```

Hope it helps!